# What is the difference between "Xpath Splitter" and "Splitter" in Spring Integration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I just want to know the difference between "Xpath Splitter"(`<int-xml:xpath-splitter>`) and "Splitter"(`</int:splitter>`) of Spring Integration framework. Can anybody explain please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple splitter can split anything. With nothing more than an `input-channel` and an `output-channel`, it will split a `Collection` of anything into individual elements.

With custom code, it can, for example, split an `Order` (with lines) into `OrderLines` etc, etc.

A `xpath-splitter` is to split an xml document into individual elements contained within the document.

Comment: Gary, So simple splitter can split anything including xml document. But, xpath-splitter can only split only xml document. A xpath-splitter is more specific. Am I correct?

Comment: Correct and you would need custom code or an xpath expression to split XML with the simple splitter.